# C# - What is the best way to center a form vertical and fixed horizontal programmatically?

Tags: c#, forms, center

I have a windows form and i want to set it in the center vertically and to a fixed point horizontally.

You can see in the code what i have tried unsuccessfully.

What is the best way to solve this?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

    //this.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    this.Location = new Point(this.CenterToScreen, 0);

    //this.CenterToScreen();
    //var rec = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;

    //int margain = 10;
    //this.Location = new Point(rec.Width - (this.Width + margain), rec.Height - (this.Height + margain));
}
```

Comment: Maybe: `this.Location = new Point(fixedX, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2);`

Comment: @JQSOFT is was just about to post the same comment

Comment: @JQSOFT - Thank you for the hint.

For some strange reason i always mix up vertical & horizontal, so it did not work as expected, so i changed it to
this.Location = new Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2, fixedY);
Thanks!

Comment: It happens. You're welcome and thank you @the_lotus too.

Comment: @JQSOFT you should write an answer to get those points

Comment: @the_lotus Just killing my retirement time and fulfilling the learning addiction. However, It's nice system though, like playing a game and gaining some points. As you know mate, the real _rep_ can't be measured by points.